# CSS/ cut an img's width when reducing the screen/window width

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I wanted to have an Image on 100% width, with a max-height. When scaling the window and you're reaching the max-height, the width should still be at a 100% but "cropping" the image bigger (provided image size is fitting). This means you can see more of the image sides (left and right) when its on a big scale window, and you can see less on a small sized window. I'll post my css try down, but i don'thave a clue how to do that at this point. Hope you're getting my issue, i'll attach a visualisation.

My Code, don't get confused, I wanted to do a slider but lets focus on only one picture now, so sliders out of the game for now:

```
.slider-inner img {
  display:none;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#main-slider {
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 500px;
  height: 450px;
  min-height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider-inner{
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  float:left;
  padding: 0px;

}
```

What i want (visualisation):

[image: visualisation of question]

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want your image to maintain its height and crop the width when window size is smaller.

Check this example:

```css
div{
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536221236547-04007cfc3d8b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=4d542ff4e10ff7de9d35d2ec8a467454&w=1000&q=80">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do this with background image:

```css
.box {
  height:200px;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/1300/300?image=1069) center top/auto 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you had "max-width:100%" and "height: auto" before. 100% is a relative unit, saying to take up 100% of the parent container's width, and auto was telling it to scale with the width while keeping aspect ratio.